# vertex shader output without any vbo input

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, shader

I'm coding in OpenGL 3.2 with C++ and I'm having an odd vertex shader problem.

So, I have a number of quads (squares actually) that have a constant size. I actually want to skip the vbo and simply use the ibo to decide on the values inside the shader.

So in doing this I've discovered OpenGL appears to have some criteria for making GLSL outputs nonactive similar to how it does for inputs. Here is my code:

```
//vertex shader
#version 140
in int p; //dummy input
out vec2 t; //finicky output
void main() { 
    p;    // line in question
    vec2 pos;
    vec4 st = vec4(-2.5, 2.5, 0.0, 5);  //const values  
    if (gl_VertexID == 0)       { pos.x = st.x; pos.y = st.z; t.x = 1; t.y = 1;}
    else if (gl_VertexID == 1)  { pos.x = st.x; pos.y = st.w; t.x = 1; t.y = 0;}
    else if (gl_VertexID == 2)  { pos.x = st.y; pos.y = st.z; t.x = 0; t.y = 1;}
    else if (gl_VertexID == 3)  { pos.x = st.y; pos.y = st.w; t.x = 0; t.y = 0;}    
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4( pos, 0.0, 1.0 ); 
}
//fragment shader
#version 140
uniform sampler2D tex;
in vec2 t;
void main() { 
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, t);
}
```

Without this dummy input and the line "p;" making p active, OpenGL makes no attempt to connect the vertex shader output with the fragment shader. Is there anyway to override this without using a dummy vbo?

Comment: Well, not all control paths assign a value to `t`. It could just be that you're experiencing the majority of vertices in your software falling outside of the 4 cases you wrote for. Are you drawing exactly 4 vertices per-draw call?

Comment: Attribute-less arendering is supported in the GL. There is no reason why you would need that "dummy input". It is a bit unclear wo me what is going on. What GL implementation are you trying this on? You are using compatibility profile. I remember that there are some issues with attribute-less rendering in compatibility profile, but I don't remember what they were.

Comment: If you do need an attribute (not sure without more research), that doesn't mean that you need a dummy VBO. You could set the value of the dummy attribute with something like `glVertexAttrib1f()`. Or not at all, if the value does not matter.

Comment: Rather that deal with this, I'm more inclined to know how to access the entire (4 vertex) vbo from each vertex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a problem with your OpenGL implementation. I could not find anything in the 3.2 spec  saying that vertex attributes are required. To the contrary, the first sentence of section "2.11.3 Vertex Attributes" clearly suggests that having vertex attributes is optional:

> Vertex shaders can deﬁne named attribute variables, which are bound to the generic vertex attributes that are set by `VertexAttrib*`.

Note that it says **"can"**, not "must".

As an experiment, I tried a small example with a shader very similar to yours, and it worked fine. This was without any vertex attributes at all (no `in` variable in the vertex shader). This was running on a MacBook Pro with Intel Iris graphics. Of course the result from one experiment is not conclusive proof, but it certainly helps confirm that this should work.

Comment: It took a lot of testing to make sure that this was the minimum it would allow for me to draw the quad. I will have to look into my setup code.